# Break feeder file into sections

Tags: gatling

I have a feeder json file which I am getting as following

```
val feeder = jsonFile("feeder.json").queue
```

and then defining the scenario. However, we will be running Gatling from Docker and I want when user pass parallelism parameter to create that my docker instances and start load testing, but then I want to separate feeder file for each instance evenly.

Is it possible?

Comment: why not create a bigger static stack that you can reference programmatically  .you can write any java or scala code in gattling ...

Comment: Because then I cant use the strategy random then I guess also I thought that feeders are more gatling way..